# Java Code : control variable in for loop

Tags: java, variables, for-loop, optimization

```
for (int page = 0; page < pageNum;) {
    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
}
```

here ++page is control variable getting modified , how to achieve in better way ?

Comment: Do you really want the preincrement (++page)?

Comment: better, in what sense? Do you just want to improve readability, or also functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the while when you do not have the control over increment operation

```
int page=0;
while(page<pageNum){
    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
for (int page = 0; page < pageNum; page++) {
    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, page+1));
}
```

Comment: To have exactly the same behavior, I think it must start at page = 1. OP is using preincrement operator. I wonder if that's actually what he wants to do, though.

Comment: no , actually inside addPage method  page variable need to be first incremented and passed  and then loop with incremented value

Comment: @user1659644 your question is unclear then. State what you want to achieve, what you are getting instead, and why this is wrong

Comment: @Fildor nah, to have exactly the same behavior, simply change this: `copy.getImportedPage(reader, page + 1)`

Comment: This can be achieved using a while instead of for

Comment: so changing `++page` to `page++` is enough?

Answer (score 1):

```
copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
```

using pre-increment operator the value will be updated first

i.e it will be called with the incremented value of page which is 1

```
copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, page++));
```

using post-increment operator the value will be updated after

i.e it will be called with the non incremented value of page which is 0

use the pre or post increment operator according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways

## 1

```
        for (int page = 1; page <= pageNum; ++page) {
            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, page));
        }
```

## 2

```
        for (int page = 1; page <= pageNum; page++) {
            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, page));
        }
```

## 3

```
        int page = 1;
        while (page <= pageNum) {
            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, page));
            page++;
        }
```

## 4

```
        int page = 0;
        while (page < pageNum) {
            page++;
            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, page));
        }
```

## 5

```
        int page = 0;
        while (page < pageNum) {
            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
        }
```